# update a table's row in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I've tried to update a row of my db's entity 'product' (with id=1) in this way:

```
ProductDao productDao = new ProductDaoImpl(manager);
Product product= productDao.retrieveById(1);
product.setName("TV 4k");
```

considering hibernate specifics, I except after 'product.setName("TV 4k")' statement that the table's relative row is going to be changed (the attribute's value 'name'), but It doesn't work.
I can update entity's rows only by EntityManager object or by other hibernate object (like Session object)?

Answer (score 1):

this would work only if you are in a transactional context with managed entity, then changing properties will be reflexed to db table at the end of the transaction. otherwise you would need to call save on the changed object

Comment: if this helps please mark it as an accepted answer